# How to execute multiple commands from a batch file, in windows command prompt, while keeping the command prompt context open?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I want to create a batch file that would execute two commands one after the other, and then keep the CMD window open. The following is what I tried, after some searching on the internet, but only the first command is getting executed.
What am I missing?

```
cmd /k C:\Users\Hp\yolo\test1\.env1\Scripts\activate && cd C:\Users\Hp\yolo\test2
```

I also tried with just one '&' instead of two, but that doesn't work either. Only the first command gets executed in both cases.

Comment: If you read the help file for CMD.exe: `Note that multiple commands separated by the command separator are accepted for string if surrounded by quotes.`

Comment: Thanks @Squashman. It works!

Answer (score 1):

```
doskey /macrofile=%~dp0adb_macros.txt 

color 9F 

cmd /K
```

For those who came here for an example of an actual answer

Comment: Yes, that. No need to squeeze everything into just one line within a batch file.